# state of the table view is changing when scrolling table view in iphone

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to add two buttons dynamically label with add and remove. When clicking add button it should change label to remove and vice verse.

I am able to perform action for add or remove buttons dynamically but the state of the table view is changing its always keeping add buttons..

thanx

Let me add my code here.

```
I am creating UI button and adding label like in for loop.Is this right approach?

UIButton *btn = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(230, 25, 73, 40) ;
btn.tag = indexPath.row+1;
btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];

for (int i=0;i<[myarrayone  count];  i++)
{ 
 for (int j=0; j<[[appDelegate AddingCartArray]   count]; j++) 
 {
  if([myarrayone objectAtIndex:i] == [[appDelegate AddingCartArray]  objectAtIndex:j])
  {
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RemovetoCart.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(Remove:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  } 
  else {
       [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"adtoCart.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(addCartClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your button click method also reload the tableView

```
[myTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: No its not working even after reloading data. Its always taking last element button.

Comment: Thanx Bonnie for your Can you please check our code.My problem its always applying last element label to all buttons.

Comment: @rajeshkarka , hey where are you writing this code, is it in the  cellForRowAtIndexPath .?? if its can you copy paste the full methood here, so that i can check, accoring to what im guessing ur creating only one instance of the label , create the label also in the cellForRowAtIndexPath